# Upgrading from ojdbc6/jdk6 to ojdbc8/jdk8 has broken TIMESTAMPTZWrapper. Cannot cast TIMESTAMPTZWrapper to TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: oracle, java-8, eclipselink, ojdbc

We have recently uplifted a major application that was written under JDK6 using ojdbc6 against an 11g Oracle database. It was uplifted to use JDK8 against the same 11g database, but we were also in the midst of upgrading to 12c. The uplifted code has been running in production against the 11g database, but slower than it was before. Against the 12c database in our QA environment, we're noticing jobs either throwing exceptions or running VERY slow. When I looked at the code, I noticed that the project team assigned to uplift the code failed to upgrade the ojdbc from 6 to at least 8. I have since done that work, but now we are getting errors from submitting the following code:

```
    Calendar endModDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    // get the timestamp from the db
    Query qry = em.createNativeQuery("select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual");
    TIMESTAMPTZWrapper tsTZWrapper = (TIMESTAMPTZWrapper)qry.getSingleResult();
```

The em is our entity manager. But when the code calls the qry.getSingleResult() member function, we get this error:

> oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.platform.database.oracle.TIMESTAMPTZWrapper

I've searched high and low for an answer, and anything that resembles an answer doesn't appear to fix my solution. This same logic is used in one other area of the code and produces the same issue. If we switch back to ojdbc6, it then works but we can't use ojdbc6 (and we really shouldn't since we're on jdk8) since we need to upgrade to Oracle 12c in the coming month.

Thanks for any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just quick comment about TIMESTAMP datatype:

- There is a bug in JDBC drivers "Bug 21891493 : JDBC SENDS TIMESTAMP SCALE OF NULL WHEN NANOSECONDS ARE ZERO", which can cause creation of excessive number child cursors in Oracle database. This bug was fixed in 12.2 JDBC drivers.
- The datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE uses internally a function to convert the this into GMT. When you create an index on it, in some cases this function based index is not used, especially when you compare this column with TIMESTAMP value of different subtype. You should compare exec plans between 11g and 12c.